# Javascript- How to pass two variables in the url?

Tags: javascript

May be this question is answered before but I'm not getting it. I'm using this code.

```
  function refresh() {
            var $var=<?php echo "$var"; ?>    
            var posm = $("#posm").val();
            var url = window.location.href;
            var index = url.indexOf('?');

            if (index > -1) {
                url = url.substring(0, index);
            }
            url += "?posm=" + posm+"?var"+$var;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```

I want to pass both variables posm and $var. posm is passed but $var is not passed. I want help to solve this issue.

Comment: The syntax is `?foo=bar&baz=42`. → `&` ←

Comment: @deceze I did not get it. Will you please be a bit elaborative

Comment: @HK007: Maybe this works: `url += "?posm=" + posm+"&var"+$var;`

Comment: No it also does not work @radon66 :(

Comment: url += "?posm="+posm &"var="+$var; I'm using this now but still not helpful @deceze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
function refresh() {
        var $var='<?php echo $var; ?>';    
        var posm = $("#posm").val();
        var url = window.location.href;
        var index = url.indexOf('?');

        if (index > -1) {
            url = url.substring(0, index);
        }
        url += "?posm=" + posm+"&var="+$var;
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped a lot. :)